# List filter to be conditional (according to results)

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

Using the "List_Filter" in admin, I would like to modify it to only show fields that have content (according to the filter).

Easiest to explain through an example.

For example,

When selecting a Category filter (eg Sunglasses), the Brand filter list will **only** list Brands that contain Sunglasses in its' filter.

Does that make sense?

How can this be achieved?

Comment: It is hard to understand exactly what you mean w/o knowing what your models look like. Can you show what your models and filters look like?

Comment: This might be what you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707002/feeding-a-current-filter-selection-to-another-custom-simplelistfilter-in-django

Comment: I want to make Django do this automatically- so that I dont have to create customlistfilters individually.

Answer (score 2):

I might think that u have to select the Next Filter according to the previous Filter.. Try to get request from the url where you pass the data

```
def lookups(self, request, model_admin):

    if request.GET.get('previous_filter') == 'True':
       return []

    if request.GET.get('current_filter') == 'False':
        return [
          # Pass your List Here
        ]
    if self.value() is None:
        return []
```